# C++ Basic error with classes

Tags: c++

```
class IEngine: public ICoreObject 
{
private:
    Network     *_Network;
    bool        _Process;

public:
    IEngine();
    ~IEngine();
    void Initial(...);
    void StartServer(unsigned short port);
    bool Process();
    void StopProcess();
    void StartProcess();
    friend void ShellCode(int id,struct NE_Bin var);

};
```

Why i cant use _Network from ShellCode ?

this is definition of ShellCode function

```
void ShellCode(int id,struct NE_Bin var) //функция-друг
{
    std::cout<<"ShellFunc Delegated"<<std::endl;
    var.data = (void *)"T";
    var.length = 1;
    //_Network->SendMessageW(id, var);
}
```

Im trying to get to the _Network class and i get errors.

Comment: Can you post the definition of `ShellCode()`?

Comment: Because of reasons... How are you attempting to use it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what errors compiler is reporting? Assuming that we are talking about compilation errors in the first place, not linker or runtime errors.

Comment: i dont have any compilation problems, i just CANT get to this instance.

Comment: @user1174133 what instance? Do you have an instance? Do you know what an instance is?

Comment: `ShellCode()` is _not_ a member function of `IEngine`.

Comment: i tried this->IEngine::_Network->bla-bla - doesnt work
IEngine::_Network-> bla bla - doesnt work

Comment: shellCode is not a member, yes, but this function should have access to IEngine

Comment: explain 'doesnt work'. what do you expect to happen? if it does compile then you DO get to this instance, although the pointer might be pointing to random location.

Comment: @user1174133, to what instance of `IEngine`?

Comment: It says something like "nonstatic nonmember function should have an instance of the caller"

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem, but names that start with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IEngine` has `ShellCode` as a friend. That means you can access `private` **members of an `IEngine` object. `_Network` is just a variable in your context, not bound to anything.

Something like this would work:

```
void ShellCode(int id,struct NE_Bin var, IEngine* pEngine)
{
    std::cout<<"ShellFunc Delegated"<<std::endl;
    var.data = (void *)"T";
    var.length = 1;
    pEngine->_Network->SendMessageW(id, var);
}
```

but you need to pass the `IEngine` as parameter:

```
IEngine* pEngine /*initialize it here*/;
ShellCode(0, NE_Bin(), pEngine);
```

or you can use a global instance inside the method (if you have one).

Answer (score 1):

Well you'd need an instance of of IEngine as a parameter to access it's member variable...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I don't consider global variables good practice so I didn't mention that. Either way he needs access to an instance of IEngine.

Comment: @Borgleader that's different. Removed dv. I agree it's not good practice, but saying "it's not possible unless you do this", when in fact it is, is just wrong.

Comment: @user1174133 _Network pointer starts off NULL.  You need to assign it to something before it contains anything.  I would advice adding a setter or adding a parameter to your constructor.

Comment: there is not a problem in adress of _Network in memory. there is a problem that i cant get to the IEngine::_Network.

Comment: @user1174133 you've declared it as a friend.  If a static friend method could access an instance without any reference to it, how do you suppose it gets that instance?  You still have to pass an instance of IEngine to the method before you can use its private members.